# Crashlytics fails for android after using gym. (get "Crashlytics has moved the submit binary outside of Crashlytics.framework directory..." error)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, crashlytics, fastlane

We're using react-native and have a fastfile set up to build and deploy iOS and Android betas. If we build-and-deploy the iOS beta, all is fine. If we build-and-deploy the Android beta, all is fine.

But if we try and do both with the same fastlane execution, the Android call to `crashlytics` fails with the following error: "Crashlytics has moved the submit binary outside of Crashlytics.framework directory as of 3.4.1. Please change :crashlytics_path to `<PODS_ROOT>/Crashlytics/submit`"

Answer (score 1):

Solution: add the following line before calling `crashlytics` for the Android build.

```
lane_context[SharedValues::IPA_OUTPUT_PATH] = nil
```

Reasoning: when the iOS build is done with `gym`, it sets this IPA_OUTPUT_PATH value. When crashlytics_helper is determining which `submit` binary to use, it checks to see if ipa_path is set -- if so, it assumes we're dealing with an iOS build, and tries to use the iOS `submit`. SO! Setting this IPA_OUTPUT_PATH to nil means crashlytics_helper **doesn't** see this as necessarily an iOS build, and we get the proper `submit` binary used.

Note that another workaround was to simply change the order and do the Android build-and-deploy first, THEN the iOS one.

Comment: BTW, not sure what the most appropriate way to handle this was - wanted to post this *somewhere* in case this helped anyone else. Just assumed posting a question and then answering it myself might be the clearest option. Also didn't **necessarily** feel this was a bug to be reported to Fastlane folks.

Comment: Please do report it, fastlane could probably add some output that `crashlytics` is using that lane context value to get the IPA to make this more obvious to users what is happening here.